# HTML.Listbox in MVC doesn't show up in FormsCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have a ASP.NET MVC application where I have a HTML.Listbox where the user can add items to it, in the webpage. It looks like this.

```
<p>
    <label for="groups">Grupper:</label>
    <%= Html.ListBox("RoleGroups", (Model != null ? new SelectList(Model.RoleGroups) : new SelectList(new List<BL.Portal.Domain.Model.RoleGroup>(){})))%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("RoleGroups")%>

    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnRemoveRoleGroup" name="brnRemoveRoleGroup" value="Ta bort gruppen" />
    <input type="button" id="btnAddRoleGrop" name="btnAddRoleGrop" href="#dialogAddRoleGroup" value="Lägg till en grupp" />
</p>
```

And in the Controller I receive the information like this.

```
[RequiresRole(RoleToCheckFor = RoleEnum.UserCreate)]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateEdit(Model.User user, bool newUser, string confirmedpassword)
```

But in my User the Properties RoleGroups is always Null so I check the Request.Form.AllKeys and can't find the key: RoleGroups in there. So I guess the information about the Html.Listbox is never sent when I do the postback!

What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oooo I must have sleept really bad tonight. There is no problem, what I did, was that I forgott to select the item in the listbox after I have added them to the listbox, so of course nothing was sent in the postback...

Well it's fixed now...

Comment: an easy solution to this is add a function call to the OnClick of the submit button that quick selects everything in the listboxes. Then nothing is missed.